# SQL SELECT AVG in Flask returns a 2D array

Tags: python-3.x, flask

(*)
I am learning both Flask and SQL. I am cloning existing, working code. I am running my Flask code in the PythonAnywhere environment.

The code I have modified starts

```
@app.route('/print_my_dogs')
def print_my_dogs():
    with sqlite3.connect("Dogs.db") as conn:
        cursor = conn.cursor()
```

then later on I have written

```
sql2 = """SELECT AVG(Dog_Age) FROM DogTbl"""
```

and execute it as follows

```
cursor.execute(sql2)
        avg_age = cursor.fetchall()
```

and pass the result on a return render_template as follows

```
return render_template("/print_my_dogs_data.html", rows=rows,avg_age=avg_age,num_dogs=num_dogs)
```

In the print_my_dogs_data.html page if I code

```
<p>Average age of dogs: {{avg_age[0][0]}}</p>
```

Then the output appears like the following:

**Average age of dogs: [(13.0,)]**

I want to get rid of the brackets. I guessed the data was actually being sent as a list.

In the print_my_dogs_data.html page if I code

```
<p>Average age of dogs: {{avg_age[0][0]}}</p>
```

This "disposes" of the brackets and the output appears like the following:

**Average age of dogs: 13.0**

which is what I want. Can someone explain why the data was either created or interpreted as a list rather than a single real value?

(* I'm not sure if this is an SQL or Flask question.) (or even jinja !)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's because you're using cursor.fetchall() which returns a list. I believe cursor.fetchone() will return a single value. SqlAlchemy works the same way.

Comment: Cursor.fetchone almost fixes it. The square brackets disappear, so a list is no longer being returned, bit the format is now (13.0000,) which I reduce to a real without parentheses by coding {{avg_age[0]}} in the HTML for the page displaying the average value.

Comment: *UPDATE* Think I found it based on RyanH explanation. Looking at: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-api-mysqlcursor-fetchone.html  ... which indicates the fetchone method returns a tuple which explains the parenthesis and the comma after the first value. Excellent. thanks !

Comment: Depending on how far along you are, you may want to consider switching to SQLAlchemy. It provides a lot of benefits, namely protection against sql injection (when not using raw sql) and db queries are returned as objects.